# How to use mPDF in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a `yii2` project and I work in front end. I make an export to `excel`, `csv`, `text`, and others in my project using `kartik` export. Because I want to export to `pdf`, then I install `kartik mPDF`. But there is an error when I want to export to `pdf`. What's the problem? This is the error:

> The pdf rendering library 'mPDF' was not found or installed at path
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\Baru\advanced/vendor/mpdf/mpdf'.

Comment: By default it should be located in `@vendor/mpdf/mpdf`, do you have it there? How did you install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change path of mpdf lib in export lib config

```
 ...
'pdfLibraryPath' => '@app/vendor/mpdf/mpdf' 
 ...
```

Check your path as error shows, I think advanced part is redundant.

Comment: I've installed mpdf by composer require kartik-v/yii2-mpdf "*" but it is installed in /vendor/kartik-v/mpdf path. how to install it in @app/vendor/mpdf/mpdf ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;
return [
 'pdf' => [
        'class' => Pdf::className(),
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
        'methods' => [
            'SetHeader' => 'Merlano PVT LTD',
            'SetFooter'=> 'Flamez',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Copy and paste this into your /common/config/main.php